# AWS Firewall rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, firewall

I come across the following rule in aws. I suppose it means,

1. the first rule #100, allow any traffic
2. - , deny any traffic

In the end, the traffic is denied , right ? What is the purpose of "allow" rule then ? What does the both rules signify ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules in ACLs are ordered (unlike security groups) from smallest to largest number with the final rule catching anything that does not match a rule.

As this is the default NACL the purpose is actually so that a person unfamiliar (or doesn't want to use) NACLs can have their network still work, they would rely on other features such as security groups or a WAF instead.

Comment: not sure if I understood your response, my question is about the "real" need for "*" rule which i mentioned above.

Comment: So in my answer the "final rule catching anything that does not match a rule." is basically trying to state its a catch all for any rules that did not match a previous rule.

Comment: i guess in the above case, it (*)  will never be used / triggered ?

Comment: Yes this is correct, however should you changed the default NACL it will still protect unmentioned ports from being allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

The default network ACL is configured to allow all traffic to flow in and out of the subnets with which it is associated.
**Each network ACL also includes a rule whose rule number is an asterisk.
This rule ensures that if a packet doesn't match any of the other numbered rules, it's denied.** You can't modify or remove this rule.

Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html

Comment: I went though the documentation before I posed this question, the point where I was disconnected what is the traffic which "doesn't" mach the first rule. It seems the first rule honours all the traffic

Comment: In your case "any traffic" is allowed in the first rule, so there is no point in checking the * rule. However, if you have a rule instead of "any traffic" rule (for example port 80 ALLOW), if the packet is destined for the HTTPS port (443) definitely denies the packet by * rule. Don't be confused with the security group as NACL lists are applicable at the subnet level.

Comment: so, you mean "unless" , there is a additional rule ,there is no use of "*" rule as everything is taken care with rule number "100" ?

Comment: no, it doesn't mean like that. In your case, your 100 rule allows all traffic to your subnet, so there is no point in * rule (which denies all traffic) because it's already allowed.
Kindly keep in mind that NACL behaves more like router ACL controlling traffic in and out of the subnet.
For example use case, if you would like to deny a particular IP from port 80 and allow others, it can be done via NACL. There are no deny rules allowed in SecurityGroup

Comment: that is what i mean, in this case, there is no point in * rule ( or not used ) , right ?

Comment: yes, for your case,  
but for any custom rule - `By default, each custom network ACL denies all inbound and outbound traffic until you add rules.`